# allure/codeception 1.1.1 is not compatible with codeception 2.3.x (latest version)

Tags: codeception, allure

- allure-framework/allure-codeception 1.1.1 requires codeception/codeception ~2.0.0
- latest codeception version is ~2.3.x

is there a work around, besides downgrading codeception ?

Comment: Resolved, they had outdated documentation. allure-framework/allure-codeception 1.2.4 is compatible with codeception 2.3

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, they had outdated documentation. allure-framework/allure-codeception 1.2.4 is compatible with codeception 2.3